# Deploy a Flutter web app in Safari 9 and iOS 9.3.5

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

Is it possible to deploy a flutter web app in **Safari 9** on an iPad with **iOS 9.3.5**?

We have a project with some old devices like the iPad. On these devices, we would run our flutter web app.

Currently, I get a **blank white screen** in Safari when the website is visited.
My other (modern) test devices (Windows 10, Android 12 ..) work fine.

[Supported flutter platforms](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/sdk/release-notes/supported-platforms) says:

> Supported platforms:
> ...
> Web Safari on El Capitan & above

and [Safari history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_(web_browser)#Safari_9):

> Safari 9 ... was released within OS X El Capitan.

For this reason, I think the old iPad is also a supported platform.??

---

**Minimum Example:**

`flutter doctor -v` output:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.5.3, on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS 5.11.0-41-generic, locale en_US.UTF-8)
    • Flutter version 2.5.3 at /home/pk/snap/flutter/common/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 18116933e7 (7 weeks ago), 2021-10-15 10:46:35 -0700
    • Engine revision d3ea636dc5
    • Dart version 2.14.4

[✗] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
    ✗ Unable to locate Android SDK.
    Install Android Studio from: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
    On first launch it will assist you in installing the Android SDK components.
    (or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#android-setup for detailed instructions).
    If the Android SDK has been installed to a custom location, please use
    `flutter config --android-sdk` to update to that location.


[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at google-chrome

[!] Android Studio (not installed)
    • Android Studio not found; download from https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
    (or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#android-setup for detailed instructions).

[✓] VS Code
    • VS Code at /snap/code/current
    • Flutter extension version 3.29.0

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • Chrome (web) • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 96.0.4664.45
```

- `lib/main.dart` (Hello world) https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/codelab#step-1-create-the-starter-flutter-app
- Build: `flutter build web --web-renderer html --release`
- Generated files (html, js ...) are moved in *nginx* 1.21.1 server
- *nginx* log (for the iPad):

  ```
   192.168.178.71 - - [05/Dec/2021:11:26:21 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3839 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 9_3_5 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Mobile/13G36 Safari/601.1" "-"
  ```
- there is no `GET /main.dart.js`; only the one line above
- (same problem without the *nginx*, via `flutter build` and port tunneling)

Comment: Have you been able to make any progress on this? I have run into a similar issue with a Flutter web app and a user on Safari 10.1.1. I have not yet found any documentation stating a specific minimum version for Safari and Flutter web but I saw your question.

Comment: @most200 No, there isn't any progress. Sadly, we have replaced the old iPads by newer hardware and our project is finsihed.